# HTML Авторизация Swift 3

Tags: swift, парсер, swift3

Необходимо авторизоваться на сайте через 2 формы и кнопку, для последующего парсинга

Как это сделать, используя библиотеку Kanna (или любую другую, если вы знаете)

Вот что у меня есть:

```
func displayURL(){
let myURLAdress = "http://someshitsite.ru/mobile/shared/default.aspx"
let myURL = URL(string: myURLAdress)
    let URLTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: myURL!){
    myData, response, error in

        guard error == nil else {return}

        let myHTMLString = String(data: myData!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        print(myHTMLString!)


        if let doc = HTML(html: myHTMLString!, encoding: .utf8) {
            print(doc.title!)



            for link in doc.xpath("//a | //link") {
                print(link.text!)

            }
        }

    }
    URLTask.resume()
}
```

А вот сами формы и кнопка

```
 <input class="textbox" tabindex="1" id="name" name="name" type="text" title="Логин">

 <input class="textbox" tabindex="2" id="password" name="password" type="password" title="Пароль">

 <input type="submit" tabindex="3" id="enter" name="enter" title="Войти" value="Войти" class="btninput">
```

Comment: И что не работает? Что не нравится?

Comment: @Bulson Да то, что я могу лишь получать исходный код, а как авторизоваться - понятия не имею

Answer (score -1):

Все очень просто любая форма это либо post либо get запрос
Вам нужно создать коннект ... т.е. Собрать строку и передать параметры в нее
let string = "[http://site.ru?name=Имя&password=Пароль](http://site.ru?name=%D0%98%D0%BC%D1%8F&password=%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C)"

Обязательно нужно понимать какой запрос вы собираетесь сделать так как у них методы реализации разные

вот как логинюсь я, советую как можно глубже изучить web POST и GET
и соответственно на swift

```
        собираем URL для post запроса 
        let myUrl = URL(string: "http://site/crapi_checkauth");

        var request = URLRequest(url:myUrl!)

        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        let postString = "login=\(login)&password=\(password)";

        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {

                // ошибка если нет соединения с интернетом или данные не пришли
                print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
                return
            }

            if error != nil {
                print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
                return
            }

            do {

                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

                guard let parseJSON = json else {
                    print("Error while parsing")
                    return
                }

                let id = parseJSON["id"] as? String

                // Login success
                if id != nil {

                    DispatchQueue.main.async( execute: {
                        appDelegate.login()

                    })

                } else {

                    DispatchQueue.main.async( execute: {

                        print("Message from =\("Ошибка тут")")
                    })

                }



            } catch {

                print(error)
            }
        }


        task.resume()
    }
```

task.resume() обязательно что бы выйти из dispatch и что бы все сработало

Comment: Странно минус влепили и даже не пояснили за что ... странные люди нынче